# How to match input with elements in list/dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, arrays, input, python-3.6

I'm very new at coding, and I'm trying to create a shop list with items and prices on it.
That is, once typed in all the items, the function should calculate the sum and stop the moment you exceed the budget.
So I wrote something like:

```
def shoplist():
    list={"apple":30, "orange":20, "milk":60......}
    buy=str(input("What do you want to purchase?")
    If buy in list:
        While sum<=budget:
            sum=sum+??
shoplist ()
```

I really don't know how to match the input of an item with the price in the list...
My first thought is to use 'if', but it's kinda impractical when you have more than 10 items on the list and random inputs.
I'm in desperate need of help....So any suggestions would be nice!! (or if you have a better solution and think me writing it this way is complete garbage... PLEASE let me know what those better solutions are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you post will not run in python. `list` is a builtin and should not be used for a variable name, and is doubly confusing since it refers to a dict object here. `input()` already returns a str so the cast has no effect. `if` and `while` should be lowercase, and there is no indentation, so we have no way of knowing the limits of those statements.

There are so many things wrong, take a look at this:

```
def shoplist(budget):
    prices = {"apple":30, "orange":20, "milk":60}

    # Initialise sum
    sum = 0

    while sum <= budget:
        buy = input("What do you want to purchase?")

        # Break out of the loop if the user hts <RETURN>
        if not buy: break

        if buy in prices:
            sum += prices[buy]   # This gets the price
        else:
            print("Invalid item", buy)

shoplist(142)
```

So what have I changed?  The budget has to come from somewhere, so I pass it in as a parameter (142, I made that up).  I initialise the sum to zero, and I moved the `while` loop to the outside.

Notice as well lots of whitespace - it makes the code easier to read and has no effect on performance.

Lots of improvements to make.  The user should be shown a list of possible items and prices and also how much budget there is left for each purchase.  Note as well that it is possible to go *over budget* since we might only have 30 in the budget but we can still buy milk (which is 60) - we need another check (`if` statement) in there!

I'll leave the improvements to you.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this as an example:

```
# this is a dictionary not a list
# be careful not using python reserved names as variable names
groceries = {
    "apple":30, 
    "orange":20, 
    "milk":60
}

expenses = 0
budget = 100
cart = []
# while statements, as well as if statements are in lower letter
while expenses < budget:
    # input always returns str, no need to cast
    user_input = input("What do you want to purchase?")
    if user_input not in groceries.keys():
        print(f'{user_input} is not available!')
        continue
    if groceries[user_input] > budget - expenses:
        print('You do not have enough budget to buy this')
        user_input = input("Are you done shopping?Type 'y' if you are.")
        if user_input == 'y':
            break
        continue
    cart.append(user_input)
    # this is how you add a number to anotherone
    expenses += groceries[user_input]
print("Shopping cart full. You bought {} items and have {} left in your budget.".format(len(cart), budget-expenses))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code to make it work, with explanation including using comments indicated by the `#` symbol.

The two most important things are that all parentheses need to be closed:

```
fun((x, y)  # broken
fun((x, y)) # not broken
```

and keywords in Python are all lowercase:

```
if, while, for, not # will work
If, While, For, Not # won't work
```

You might be confused by `True` and `False`, which probably should be lowercase. They've been that way so long that it's too late to change them now.

```
budget = 100 # You need to initialize variables before using them.

def shoplist():
    prices = {         # I re-named the price list from list to prices
        'apple'  : 30, # because list is a reserved keyword. You should only
        'orange' : 20, # use the list keyword to initialize list objects.
        'milk'   : 60, # This type of object is called a dictionary.
    } # The dots .... would have caused an error.
    # In most programming languages, you need to close all braces ().
    # I've renamed buy to item to make it clearer what that variable represents.
    item = input('What do you want to purchase? ')
    # Also, you don't need to cast the value of input to str; 
    # it's already a str.
    if item in prices:
        # If you need an int, you do have to cast from string to int.
        count = int(input('How many? ')) 
        cost = count*prices[item] # Access dictionary items using [].
        if cost > budget:
            print('You can\'t afford that many!')
        else:
            # You can put data into strings using the % symbol like so:
            print('That\'ll be %i.' % cost) # Here %i indicates an int.
    else:
        print('We don\'t have %s in stock.' % item) # Here %s means str.

shoplist()
```

A lot of beginners post broken code on StackOverflow without saying that they're getting errors or what those errors are. It's always helpful to post the error messages. Let me know if you have more questions.